# jQuery in Wordpress not working the same way as in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to run a js/jQuery script that hides elements of a certain class on certain wordpress pages. Hiding them works when typing it into the console:

```
jQuery('div.pretty > long > selector').hide()
```

The script looks something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('div.pretty > long > selector').hide(0, console.log('hidden!'))

})
```

It seems to execute since I get the console log callback, but the elements are not hidden.

I also tried the following, but with the same result:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('div.pretty > long > selector').hide(0, console.log('hidden!'))

})
```

Any hints on how to fix this are very much appreciated!

Comment: do you mean, if you implement in console it works, if you write in js file it wont?

Comment: How are the elements being put in the DOM? Do they exist when the page loads, or are they added later. By AJAX, for example.

Comment: it seems it is inside the popup

Comment: @charankumar yes exactly. it works in console but not in js file.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am not sure how they are loaded. It's a part of subscription options on product pages, so I'd assume they are present when page is loaded. but I may be wrong.

Comment: does it work if you do something like `$('element').css('display', 'none')` note: this is bad practice but a good way to see if it's the `.hide()` function playing up or something else

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that you are enqueuing your script, and telling WordPress it requires jQuery. This can be done like so inside of your theme's `functions.php` (if the theme isn't custom, create a child theme first) or inside of a plugin:

```
function enqueue_jquery_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/your_script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery_scripts' );
```

Next, make sure you use `jQuery` instead of the `$` shorthand, as WordPress' bundled jQuery runs in `noconflict` mode.

Update: If the elements are indeed loaded through AJAX, perhaps instead of using `document.ready()` try `document.ajaxComplete()` instead:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  // blah
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already implemented what you suggest. The script does run with both approaches mentioned. So by now I assume the elements I want to hide are indeed loaded through ajax and thus not present at document ready..

Comment: @citivin, maybe this utility can help: [waitForKeyElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039001/toggling-click-handler-using-waitforkeyelementswaitForKeyElements)

Comment: @citivin I've updated my answer with the possibility of AJAX being used in mind.